# "Quasi-waterfall" chart - one measure as proportion of another measure

Tags: excel, charts, tableau-api, waterfall

I would like to build a kind of waterfall chart in Tableau and unfortunately I ran out of ideas. The ultimate goal would be to have the same chart as produced by Excel.[image: same chart] But for the beginning it would be nice to have at least the column named "weight", which is a result of calculation on 2 measures: *not served* divided by the total of *ordered* - see linked image above for better visual understanding.

Comment: Hi Pali, thanks for the prototype images.  What have you tried in Tableau so far?

Answer (score 0):

Update: the calculation you need is:
attr([Not Served])/WINDOW_SUM(sum([Ordered]))

You need to drag both measures into the Tableau viz, right-click weight and select dual axis. Then you will probably need to reverse the axis for weight, and setup the fixed ranges for each, as you have in your image.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. For your solution firstly you need to calculate the column "wight" - and that's the point where I am stuck at the moment.